# How can i map one entity to two databases (MongoDb and Neo4j) with custom properties in each

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, neo4j

I have a user entity which i want to save in two databases, one in MongoDb and one in Neo4j:

```
@Node("User")
@Document
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
  @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
  private String id;
  //some other fields
  private Set<SomeObject> objects = new HashSet<>();
  //getters and setters
}
```

These are my dependencies for both databases:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rx-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Now imagine that i want the set of objects to be saved in my MongoDb but not in my Neo4j database. If i mark this as @Transient it won't be saved in any one of them. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is spring-data-neo4j in your dependencies?

Comment: No. There's only spring-data-neo4j-rx.

Comment: Spring Data Neo4j RX (https://github.com/neo4j/sdn-rx - repo is archived) has been replaced by Spring Data Neo4j 6 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j). You should upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be *some* support for this kind of scenario a long time ago (around Spring Data Neo4j 3), but it appears to be very complex to properly support, which is why there is no built-in support for partial entities anymore.

For instance, how do you roll back a transaction if part of the entity is properly persisted (to datastore A) and the other is not (to datastore B)? What if the rollback fails?

If you still want to go down that route, I think you'd need to explicitly use `Neo4jTransactionManager` and `MongoTransactionManager` (or their reactive variants) and rely on [JTA](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jta.html) or similar to coordinate the separate transactions.

For your entities, I would assume that moving away from the Spring Data Commons annotations and using the datastore-specific annotations could work.